# How do I remove the spindle stuck in the door?

Tags: doors, doorknob

I have removed the door knobs from either side of the spindle but I cannot push the spindle through to be able to remove the rest of the mechanism.

I have tried to push the latch in and remove the spindle but that does not seem to release it.

Any ideas?[image]

[image: This is the other side of the spindle and the knob which was attached before the spindle snapped.]

Comment: Can we get a picture of both knobs where the spindle attaches?

Comment: I have updated with an additional image now Lee.

Comment: Start by removing the two screws that were hidden by the doorknob.

Comment: Why not remove the round white plastic disc that is screwed into the door? It could have a notch embedded into the spindle.

Comment: Try a hammer and punch to drift it out

Answer (score 3):

As the door knob has been broken off its likely that the spindle is bent. (It looks bent in the second picture.) As already suggested remove the white disk (probably part of the collar) then tap the spindle out from the non-broken side.

You may need to 'tap' vigorously, at least to start with. The lock mechanism may well already be scrap.

Comment: And start by taking off that beauty ring too!

Answer (score 0):

That white plastic round part needs to come off anyway. Gentle (at first) tapping should get the spindle moving. From one side, then the other. If it's really stuck, WD40, squirted and left for a time, may free it from captivity, but tapping from either side will eventually make it escape.

Answer (score 0):

I had literally the exact problem and used plier to yank spindle out.

https://youtu.be/yBia9xxvu1E

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).